# Module not found: Can't resolve 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css' in 'C:\react-form-validation-demo\src'

Tags: reactjs

I am newbie in react.js. I have been following instruction in [how-to-do-simple-form-validation-in-reactjs](https://learnetto.com/blog/how-to-do-simple-form-validation-in-reactjs) and I can run http://localhost:3000/

But after adding bootstrap in `index.js`, I got this error

> ```
> Failed to compile ./src/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve
> 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css' in
> 'C:\react-form-validation-demo\src'
> ```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

If I remove these two lines below, it works:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
```

Comment: In order to import as css file into js you would need to be using some sort of bundler like webpack. This tutorial is using `create-react-app` though, which should take care of all this for you.

Comment: i think my sample is not using webpack

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Bootstrap version 4, the file 'bootstrap-theme.css' has been removed, according to [the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21078). See the [change history](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#global-changes) for details.

If you want to continue using version 4, remove this import, else downgrade to version 3.

Answer (score 20):

This error is caused by a misconfiguration, version mismatch or corrupted bootstrap install.

If you've got bootstrap and react-bootstrap installed already via some variation of:

> `npm install --save bootstrap@^4.0.0-alpha.6  react-bootstrap@^0.32.1`

(*Check if your `package.json` contains "bootstrap" and "react-bootstrap" if your not sure.*)

Just install a different version of bootstrap and rebuild your project. That should replace or add that file (`bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css`) to that folder. 
A lower version of bootstrap worked for me as recommended in my create-react-app generated README.md:

> `npm install --save react-bootstrap bootstrap@3`
>
> ### Adding Bootstrap
>
> You don’t have to use [React
>   Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io) together with React but
>   it is a popular library for integrating Bootstrap with React apps. If
>   you need it, you can integrate it with Create React App by following
>   these steps:
>
> Install React Bootstrap and Bootstrap from npm. React Bootstrap does
>   not include Bootstrap CSS so this needs to be installed as well:
>
> `sh npm install --save react-bootstrap bootstrap@3`
>
> Alternatively you may use `yarn`:
>
> `sh yarn add react-bootstrap bootstrap@3`

Answer (score 20):

Adding the solution to the cause I ran into - it was my miss, but still unclear when reading the other answers.

If `react-bootstrap` is installed solo like this:

```
npm install --save react-bootstrap
```

then `bootstrap` will be missing.  Try the following to correct:

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

The *correct* way to install initially is as follows:

```
npm install --save react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

Comment: For those who cames here because of mispelled `booSTrap`, [which refers to another valid package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/boostrap), should have title's question error. This answer solved my problem.

Comment: Is there really a valid package named `booSTrap`?  That sounds like a perfect name for a supply-chain attack.

Comment: Yes, just follow the link in my previous comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/boostrap - I understand your reference, but I'm curious: what is the english expression you are thinking about?

Comment: No English expression.  By "supply-chain attack," I am referring to someone publishing a package under a name that is very close to a real, popular package, and putting nefarious content into it.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now. Yes, I agree.

Answer (score 19):

reinstall the bootstrap and don't forget to mention --save to the command to save it to the node modules this solved the problem for me.

```
sudo npm install bootstrap --save
```

Comment: worked for me with the path: import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

Comment: Do not use sudo for installing dependencies! Sudo should only be used when really, really necessary - it can cause many issues

Answer (score 8):

I got the same problem and this is how I resolved the problem. 
First of all delete the *node_modules* directory from the project and then install bootstrap with below command.

```
npm install 
npm i bootstrap
```

Then, you can add the below import to the index.js

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Answer (score 8):

Install the bootstrap using the below command.

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

Then include the below line in the index.js file.

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Answer (score 5):

```
npm install --save bootstrap@^4.0.0-alpha.6  react-bootstrap@^0.32.1
```

i face same problem but after installing above packages it work well,
may b you should also install same packages

Answer (score 4):

```js
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Source: [github](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1325#issuecomment-527583125)

Answer (score 3):

Remove

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'
```

That worked for me.

Comment: It changes the look and feel of my web application.

Comment: Looks like after installing the import isn't needed for it to load bootstrap styles correctly. So if you are having trouble with this, try installing as @Higgs Bogson describes and then removing the import. (B/c duh, removing the import removes the error, but I doubt you're here looking for a solution because you didn't need it in the first place.)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, but my project was not created with `create-react-app`, mine was using `webpack`.

I can answer how I resolved it for webpack, maybe you can find the changes required for `create-react-app` after you go through this answer.

First I installed these two modules- 
`style-loader` 
`css-loader`

Then I modified the `webpack.config.js` file and added these lines inside the `module.rules` array.

```js
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'style-loader'
},
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'css-loader',
  query: {
    modules: true,
    localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
  }
}
```

This resolved the error in my project. You can also refer to this Github issue thread once, may be that may help you: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/301

Answer (score 2):

```
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your question to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have bootstrap in package.json file .
If it is there remove and  use the below commands to reinstall or install if it is not there.

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to install both packages reactstrap and bootstrap by running these commands:

```
npm i reactstrap
npm i bootstrap
```

Answer (score 1):

Some times is writing error

boo***tst***rap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

boo***st***rap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

check this tip, sometimes happend

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can also check that your package.json imported name of dependancy are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that when you installed bootstrap you were not in the directory that `create-react-app` created (that was the source of my problem). You can check with: `npm list`, which looks for locally installed packages.

Then scroll all the way to the top and see if you can find bootstrap listed there.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the npm server than restart it. It'll be solved if you installed the packages perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `bootstrap` and `react-bootstrap` are installed.

```
npm install bootstrap react-bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

I had simply reinstalled the previous Bootstrap version which I installed in my project folder and it worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

from the "resource/js/app.js" remove `require('./bootstrap')`