# How to add bootstrap in react?

Tags: java, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

```
import './App.css';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
function App(){
    return(
        <div className="my-todo-app">
            <TodoList/>
            
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;
```

It showed like this error.

> ./src/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve
> 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' in 'E:\React
> Work\assesment\my-todo-app\src'

How Do I solve this problem?

Comment: look, pls - https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1325 **and** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48847885/module-not-found-cant-resolve-bootstrap-dist-css-bootstrap-theme-css-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this blog to know about how to add bootstrap in react, "How a designer can start React JS"

Blog Link:- https://blog.yudiz.com/how-a-designer-can-start-react-js/